# How to display float on screen? Libgdx

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I'm trying to display seconds on screen, in other words float, but I just knew that this is not possible:

```
font.draw(batch,float,x,y);
```

Also how do you compute for second, I wan't to print something like this on screen:1.2sec,3.2seconds. This is what I do instead which gives me a lot of decimal places.

```
seconds+=1*deltaTime;
```

Comment: What does your seconds variable represents ? does it represent the amount of time since you entered the screen ?

Comment: yes, when you start the game the seconds should start counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your float into String:

```
Float.toString(seconds)
```

For your "seconds" variable just store the time when your game start

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then display like this

```
font.draw(batch,Float.toString((Float)((System.currentTimeMillis() -startTime)/1000f),x,y);
```

You should call it everyframe otherwise it would be erased when the new frame is drawn.

Comment: I did this but I get an error, is this code should be called once or every frame?

Answer (score 0):

To format a `float` into a `String` with a certain number of decimal places, you would use the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

```
float x = 2.3456;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
String formatted = df.format(x);
font.draw(batch, formatted, x, y);
```

You might want to test that this works when you export as JavaScript and to Android through libGDX, but this is the standard Java approach.